# ConcurrentModificationException when removing item in nested loops

Tags: java, loops, nested, concurrentmodification

This is my code, and I obtained a `ConcurrentModificationException` when I removed an element. I do not understand why `itrGrupo1` is affected by removing an element in `itrGrupo2`.

The exception occurs at: `Instancia inst1=(Instancia) itrGrupo1.next()` when the second while is finished.

```
for (int i=0; i<lstPrimeraAgrupacion.size();i++){

  List grupo1=new ArrayList();
  List grupo2=new ArrayList();
  grupo1=(List) lstPrimeraAgrupacion.get(i);         
  grupo2=(List) lstPrimeraAgrupacion.get(i);         

  Iterator itrGrupo1 = grupo1.iterator();
  while(itrGrupo1.hasNext()) {

      List nuevoGrupo=new ArrayList();

      Instancia inst1=(Instancia) itrGrupo1.next();         
      int edad1=Integer.valueOf(inst1.getEdadH());
      int carnet1=Integer.valueOf(inst1.getCarnetH());
      int antigCli1=Integer.valueOf(inst1.getAntigCli());

      Iterator itrGrupo2 = grupo2.iterator();
      while(itrGrupo2.hasNext()) {

          Instancia inst2=(Instancia) itrGrupo2.next();
          int edad2=Integer.valueOf(inst2.getEdadH());
          int carnet2=Integer.valueOf(inst2.getCarnetH());
          int antigCli2=Integer.valueOf(inst2.getAntigCli());

          if(cond){
              nuevoGrupo.add(inst2);
              itrGrupo2.remove();
          }

      }

      // Put in the final list
      if (!nuevoGrupo.isEmpty()){
          lstNuevosGrupos.add(nuevoGrupo);
      }

  }

}
```

Comment: The lines `grupo1=(List) lstPrimeraAgrupacion.get(i);` and `grupo2=(List) lstPrimeraAgrupacion.get(i);` mean that you're fetching references to the **same list**. So, changing the contents of `grupo1` will also change the contents of `grupo2`, since they are *references* to the *same object*.

Comment: Thanks Shotgun ninja, I tried to do this, but it didn´t fix the problem:                List lstPrimeraAgrupacion2=new ArrayList();      
                              lstPrimeraAgrupacion2=lstPrimeraAgrupacion;

Comment: I'm assuming `lstPrimeraAgrupacion` is a `List<List<Instancia>>`, or a `List` of `List`s of `Instancia` objects. If that is the case, then I *believe* you need to do `grupo1.addAll(lstPrimeraAgrupacion.get(i));` instead of `grupo1=(List) lstPrimeraAgrupacion.get(i);`, so you duplicate the contents of the list into your new list instead of getting a reference to the existing list.

Comment: it works, thank you very much Shotgun Ninja

Comment: I'll rewrite it as an answer.

Comment: if you're using **Java 1.5 or above**, then use generics instead of raw types on your `ArrayList<T>`...

Comment: @EpicPandaForce There are still plenty of places which use Java 1.5+ code without generics. (I work for one)

Comment: @ShotgunNinja I question the possible code quality of such a place, and dread for the `RuntimeException`s. I'm also glad we actually at least try to get with the times, Java 1.5 and generics came out about... 11 years ago, after all.

Comment: I question it too. Frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem exists due to the following lines:

```
List grupo1=new ArrayList();
List grupo2=new ArrayList();
grupo1=(List) lstPrimeraAgrupacion.get(i);         
grupo2=(List) lstPrimeraAgrupacion.get(i);
```

The first two lines of this create two new `ArrayList`s, but the lines following them make `grupo1` and `grupo2` point to the same, existing list. I feel that this is desired for `grupo2`, since you are *modifying* it, and it looks like the desired effect of this code is to modify `lstPrimeraAgrupacion`'s `i`th sub-list. (I'm assuming that `lstPrimeraAgrupacion` is a `List<List<Instancia>>`, or a list of sub-lists of `Instancia` objects.)

What the body of your code does is look through `grupo1` for any elements that match a condition, and then removes them from `grupo2`. However, if these two variables reference the same `List<Instancia>` object, then modifying `grupo2` will also change what your iterator over `grupo1` has access to, potentially leaving it in a broken state (which is why you got the exception).

Now, there are far better approaches to resolving the problem of iterating over a list and removing elements, but the way that you've designed your code, the lowest-impact solution would be to simply duplicate the elements into a new `List`, and use that as a snapshot of the old list, while you remove elements as needed from the actual list. To do this, you can change the above code to the following:

```
List grupo1=new ArrayList();
List grupo2=null;
grupo1.addAll((List) lstPrimeraAgrupacion.get(i)); // Copies the list into our new ArrayList pointed to by grupo1
grupo2=(List) lstPrimeraAgrupacion.get(i); // Makes grupo2 point to the existing List so we can modify it directly.
```